# Same distance of text elements using css/jsf-2

Tags: css, jsf-2, distance

[image]

You can see, that the distance bewteen email and the email is equal to the distance of member since and the date.

My code for this (using jsf-2):

```
    <h:outputText value="email" />
    <p:spacer width="50" height="10" />
    <h:outputText value="sasdrftg@rfghre.de" />
    <br></br>
    <h:outputText value="member since" />

    <p:spacer width="50" height="10" />
    <h:outputText value="#{userUtilityBean.user.registered.time}">
        <f:convertDateTime type="both" dateStyle="short" />
    </h:outputText>
```

My css is simple:

```
.form-userdata {
position: absolute;
left: 30% !important;
color: blue !important;
```

}

How can I align the email to the "x-position" of the date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such kind of information presentation, use a `h:panelGrid` instead

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputText value="email" />
    <h:outputText value="sasdrftg@rfghre.de" />

    <h:outputText value="member since" />
    <h:outputText value="#{userUtilityBean.user.registered.time}">
        <f:convertDateTime type="both" dateStyle="short" />
    </h:outputText>
</h:panelGrid>
```